# OSM showing wrong distance between 2 points

Tags: openstreetmap, distance, osrm

I am facing an issue with OSRM.

Source - 19.04835   72.91024
destination - 19.0612081    72.9241063

The actual distance is 3.1 km but OSRM is showing as 13.5 km

This is the script I am running
r = requests.get(f"http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/car/{lon_1},{lat_1};{lon_2},{lat_2}?overview=false""")

Any thoughts on how it can solved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is the resulting route: https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_car&route=19.04938%2C72.91099%3B19.06203%2C72.92219#map=14/19.0429/72.8992

The closest road to your start [19.04835,72.91024](https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=19.04835&mlon=72.91024#map=17/19.04835/72.91024) is the Eastern Freeway. So technically the resulting route is correct (although there is likely no connection to the freeway at this point). If you want to start from one of the nearest minor roads then you have to adjust your start point accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For the points given in this case, I get a distance of 2.97km.